# Pandas: groupby column, merge rows of lists into a single column for group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

f1 = [['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'jkl'], ['mno', 'pqr'], ['stu', 'vwx'], ['yz', 'xx'], ['yx', 'zx'], ['text', 'more'], ['stuff', 'here'], ['last', 'one']]

f2 = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3']

groups = ['GROUP A', 'GROUP A', 'GROUP A', 'GROUP B', 'GROUP B', 'GROUP B', 'GROUP C', 'GROUP C', 'GROUP C']


df = pd.DataFrame({'Groups': groups, 'Feature 1': f1, 'Feature 2': f2})
df


# DataFrame print:
    Groups    Feature 1   Feature 2
0   GROUP A   [abc, def]      1
1   GROUP A   [ghi, jkl]      1
2   GROUP A   [mno, pqr]      1
3   GROUP B   [stu, vwx]      2
4   GROUP B   [yz, xx]    2
5   GROUP B   [yx, zx]    2
6   GROUP C   [text, more]    3
7   GROUP C   [stuff, here]   3
8   GROUP C   [last, one]     3
```

I am trying to group the data by the 'Group' column in such a way that I can generate a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Groups      Feature 1                                Feature 2
GROUP A     [abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr]           1
GROUP B     [stu, vwx, yz, xx, yx, zx]               2
GROUP C     [text, more, stuff, here, last, one]     3
```

In other words, my groups are repeated in the 'Groups' column, each repeat corresponding to an individual list belonging to that group.

I want to eliminate the multiple repeats of the groups in the 'Groups' column and combine all of the individual lists associated with each group into a single, merged list containing all elements in a single row.

I have experimented with `groupby()` a bit and searched around, but I am struggling to implement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `GroupBy` and aggregate on the column containing lists with `sum` to concatenate the lists within the group and on `Feature 2` with `first`:

```
df.groupby('Groups').agg({'Feature 1':'sum', 'Feature 2':'first'}).reset_index()

   Groups                        Feature 1          Feature 2
0  GROUP A        [abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno, pqr]         1
1  GROUP B            [stu, vwx, yz, xx, yx, zx]         2
2  GROUP C  [text, more, stuff, here, last, one]         3
​
```